# Comparing Kernel Density Estimation plots

Tags: r, kernel-density

I am actually a novice to R and stats.. Could something like this be done in R

Determining the density estimates of two samples ( 2 Vectors )..??
 I have done this Using R and obtained 2 density curves for the 2 samples using kernel density estimation ..

Is there anyway to quantitatively compare how similar/Dissimilar the density estimates of 2 samples are..?

I am trying to find out which data sample exhibits has a similar distribution to a particular distribution..

I am using R Language... Can somebody please help..??

Comment: YOu have an answer that was very helpful. Please click on the V-sign on the left of that answer to accept it, and do the same with the answers on your previous questions. This tells other people passing by that it was a correct answer. People will be less and less helpful when you don't acknowledge their answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Kolmogorov-Smirnov test (`ks.test`) to compare two distributions.  Cramer-von-Mises test is another one. There is this PDF [Fitting Distributions with R](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Ricci-distributions-en.pdf) where they also list other tests that are available (although the `nortest` package that he uses only tests for normality).

Comment: It seems that ks.test can be used only to compare to standard distributions such as Weibull, not comparing two non-standard

Comment: @Toothrot, ks.test can test two arbitrary distributions; you optionally can refer to a named cumulative distribution family.

Answer (score 4):

Apprentice Queue is right about using the Kolmogorov-Smirnoff test, but I wanted to add a warning:  don't use it on its own.  You should visually compare the distributions as well, either with two kernel density plots or histograms, or with a qqplot.  Human brains are very good at playing spot-the-difference.

Comment: Good point and, interestingly, that is exactly what @Pradeep proposes as his problem which neither answer currently offered really gets at.

Comment: @Simpson, actually Pradeep's problem was he needed a quantitative procedure not a qualitative one. He had already calculated their densities and therefore could plot them.

Answer (score 0):

You can try calculating the [Earth mover's distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth_mover%27s_distance)